# Jqgrid buildselect function not called even when response is returned from server resource define using dataUrl

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to populate my custom select element in jqgrid used for searching purpose.I am using ajaxselectoptions, dataurl and buildselect to build my custom select element. The below code is used

```
 ajaxSelectOptions: {
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    console.log("getGenders",response);
                }
            },

-- the below code is a part of colmodel option

            name: 'empGender',
            editable: true,
            edittype:'select',
            formatter:'select',
            editoptions:{value:":All;M:Male;F:Female"},
            stype: 'select',
            search: true,
            searchoptions: {
                dataUrl: './getGenders',
                buildSelect: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var ele = '<select>';
                    $.each(data, function(index, object) {
                        ele+='<option value='+object.id+'>'+object.value+'</option>';
                    });
                    ele=ele+'</select>';
                    //console.log(ele);
                    return ele;
                }
            }
```

My success function is executing and printing the expected output in console.But after that when i am trying to build my select element using buildselect function under search options it is not happening as it is not executing at all.
Could someone please help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Comment: @TonyTomov Thanks for your reply, Yes the version used is 4.6,is that the reason why it is not able to render the element.Which minimum version should be used to enable this?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the definition of ajaxSelectOptions. In this object you define success function which overwrite the success function in jqGrid. In order you code to work you should remove this event in ajaxSeletOptions.

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
-- the below code is a part of colmodel option

        name: 'empGender',
        editable: true,
        edittype:'select',
        formatter:'select',
        editoptions:{value:":All;M:Male;F:Female"},
        stype: 'select',
        search: true,
        searchoptions: {
            dataUrl: './getGenders',
            buildSelect: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var ele = '<select>';
                $.each(data, function(index, object) {
                    ele+='<option value='+object.id+'>'+object.value+'</option>';
                });
                ele=ele+'</select>';
                //console.log(ele);
                return ele;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. Are you saying that since I am defining success function in ajaxselectoptions it is going to override builtselect function under search option for that particular column? Because there is no success event executed in jqgrid when the request to server is success.Load complete is executed if the request is successful and if it is not load error is executed.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite buildselect, it overwrites ajax success function which is executed in jqGrid through **dataUrl** url. dataUrl mean that there is ajax in jqgrid from where to get data for your buildselect

Comment: Actually buildSelect is defined within success function in ajax call when try to build the select dynamically and since it is overwritten from ajaxSelectOptions it is not excuted